# Am I meant to allocate a /64 to every host?

Tags: ipv6, subnet

I have been reading conflicting sources and seeing different behaviours about how a CPE router should be assigning IPv6 addresses.

[RFC3633](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3633#section-5.1) seems to imply that each host should get /64, while [RFC6204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6204#section-4.3) says that the router should assign a /64 to each of its LAN interfaces (which is still one /64 per host for a simple residential network, right?)

Meanwhile, I have been assigned a /56 (via a tunnel) and I have a router running OpenWRT Barrier Breaker.
SLAAC on my computer only gives me IPs from the first /64; and in an attempt to allocate each computer a complete /64 automatically (rather than through manual assignment), both DHCPv6 servers (odhcpd and dnsmasq) I've tried still only hands out IPs in the first /64.
More specifically with dnsmasq, I've tried `dhcp-range=2001:xxxx:e001:c501::,2001:xxxx:e001:c5ff::` but it errors with "inconsistent DHCPv6 range", and `dhcp-range=2001:xxxx:e001:c500::,56` gives "prefix length must be at least 64".

So the actual DHCPv6 (and SLAAC) seems to be only using a single /64 for the entire network, but I've only read that each host should get a /64.
So which is right?

**Edit:**
If a /64 for the entire network is the "correct" assignment for a residential site, why is it a [best current practice](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6177) to allocate a /56 or /48 to each site?
I was under the assumption that it was so that each host would be allocated a /64 by the router.

P.S., The IPs on my router's interfaces look like this:

```
$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fed4:3678/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 
    inet6 2001:xxxx:e001:c500::1/56 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdd0:da3b:f524::1/56 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fed4:3678/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth0.2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fed4:3678/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fed4:3678/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: sit1: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 
    inet6 2001:xxxx:f000::32af/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7892:987e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c0a8:101/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: No, you're meant to assign a /64 to each subnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each broadcast domain gets a /64. If you have your hosts isolated, so that there should only be one per subnet, you can assign a whole /64 for a single host. This is mostly used for servers, where you use static IP assignements anyway. If you see the need for SLAAC or stateful DHCPv6, you probably should assign a /64 for a whole network segment, not a single host.

Comment: Then what does RFC6204 mean by "The IPv6 CE router MUST assign a separate /64 from its delegated prefix(es) for each of its LAN interfaces."? Also see edits to the question

Comment: See the definition of a LAN interface in the same RFC: "LAN interface: an IPv6 CE router's attachment to a link in the end-user network.  Examples are Ethernets (simple or bridged), 802.11 wireless, or other LAN technologies.  An IPv6 CE router may have one or more network-layer LAN interfaces."

Usually a simple SoHo router will have a single wan and a single LAN interface, but a built-in switch that allows you to attach multiple devices to the LAN interface.

Answer (score 7):

IPv6 usually uses a /64 per subnet. Routers send a Router Advertisement or RA to the LAN. This RA contains the basic settings for the LAN like which prefixes (often a single /64) to use, whether the router can be used as a default gateway, whether hosts are allowed to auto-configure themselves and whether there is a DHCPv6 server on the LAN (and what kind of DHCPv6 server: stateful or stateless). The default DNS resolvers can also be sent in the RA.

Yes, this means that it is no problem at all to run a network without DHCP and have everything work automatically.

If hosts are allowed to auto-configure themselves they will take the /64 announced in the RA and give themselves one or more addresses in that /64. What probably confuses you is that this is shown as e.g. `2001:db8:aa:b::12ab/64`. This doesn't mean that the host gets the whole /64, it means that the host *is part* of that /64 on the LAN with address `2001:db8:aa:b::12ab`.

DHCPv6 can work in two ways: stateful and stateless. Stateful is similar to what you are used to in IPv4: the DHCP server assigns addresses to hosts and gives them configuration info like DNS resolves, NTP servers etc. Stateless is simpler: it only provides the configuration info. Which DHCPv6 server type is available on the LAN is communicated in the RA.

The combination of auto-configuration and stateless DHCPv6 is very common.

Comment: Please see edits to the question